# Is there a version of pdfTex that does not ignore non-pdf special commands?

Tags: pdftex, plain-tex

To make hyperlinks to theorems in plaintex one can use commands that are available in a file called Hyperbasics. When running pdftex instead of tex on the file, Miktex ignores some of the special commands of Hyperbasics. 
This leads to the question in the title.

Comment: The entire point of specials is that they are driver dependent. Presumably, the ones you are talking about are PostScript specials: you'll therefore need to run in DVI mode and use `dvips` to convert through to PostScript.

Comment: You might try the hyper-reference features of `eplain` (documented in `eplain.pdf`. You can just put `\input eplain` at the start of most plain-tex documents.

Comment: you can use `xetex` instead of `pdftex` it can handle `\special` commands and has the pdf output by default.

Comment: Do you mind providing a MWE so that we may test it on our systems?